# jQPLOT - Memory leak

Tags: jquery, memory, memory-leaks, jqplot

I want to build a chart with interactively refreshing. I using jqPlot, but by trying to update the graph with calling replot() or redraw it causes a huge browser memory leak. Do you have any idea how i can fix it?

```
function crateChart() {
    var s1 = [['a',6], ['b',8], ['c',14], ['d',20]];
    var s2 = [['a', 8], ['b', 12], ['c', 6], ['d', 9]];

    this.plot = $.jqplot('chart', [s1, s2], {
        seriesDefaults: {
        renderer:$.jqplot.DonutRenderer,
        rendererOptions:{
            sliceMargin: 3,
            startAngle: -90,
            showDataLabels: true,
            dataLabels: 'value'
            }
        }
    });
}

function update () {
    ChartTester.plot.series[0].data = [
        ['a', Math.random() * 100],
        ['b', Math.random() * 100],
        ['c', Math.random() * 100],
        ['d', Math.random() * 100]
    ];

    ChartTester.plot.destroy();
    $('#chart *').unbind();
    $('#chart').empty();
    ChartTester.plot.redraw();
}
```

Comment: Is it an option to build the graph on the server side and then send the finished image to the browser?

Comment: Which browser(s) have the memory leak?  There's a long history of jqPlot and memory problems with IE < 9 in particular.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a "plug and play" solution, but a good example of dynamically data update  on JQPlot chart to inspire you : http://jsfiddle.net/fracu/HrZcj/

Basically, the update function is like that :

```
function updateSeries() {
    myData.splice(0, 1);
    x = (new Date()).getTime();
    y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    myData.push([x, y]);

    plot1.series[0].data = myData;
    plot1.resetAxesScale();
    plot1.axes.xaxis.numberTicks = 10;
    plot1.axes.y2axis.numberTicks = 15;
    plot1.replot();
}
```