# updating jqplot bar chart after fixed timeinterval

Tags: jqplot

How can I update jqplot bar chart after fixed time interval(for example 10 seconds)? I wrote the following code in which y axis data is randomly generated but it is not updating after fixed time interval.

```
<?php 
$x = array();
$y = array();
for($i=0;$i<50; $i++)
{
$x[] = $i;
$y[] = rand(10, 200);
}

$x_data = json_encode($x);
$y_data = json_encode($y);

Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('chart_big',"
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;
    var s2 = $y_data;
    var ticks = $x_data;

    plot5 = $.jqplot('chart_big', [s2], {
        // Only animate if we're not using excanvas (not in IE 7 or IE 8)..
        animate: !$.jqplot.use_excanvas,
        seriesDefaults:{
            renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
            pointLabels: { show: true }
        },
        axes: {
            xaxis: {
                renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                ticks: ticks
            }
        },
        highlighter: { show: false }
    });

    $('#chart1').bind('jqplotDataClick',
        function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
            $('#info1').html('series: '+seriesIndex+', point: '+pointIndex+', data: '+data);
        }
    );
    $('a[href=\"#yw1_tab_4\"]').on('shown', function(g) {
            if (plot5._drawCount === 0) {
            plot5.replot();
        }
    });


   setInterval(function () {

      s2 = $y_data;
      ticks = $x_data;
      plot5.series[0].data = s2; 
      plot5.replot();
   }, 10000);


});
");
?>
```

Comment: please refer to this post:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18535670/jqplot-animate-data-change-without-reloading-graph/18539858](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18535670/jqplot-animate-data-change-without-reloading-graph/18539858)

Comment: Thanks Gyandeep it gave me idea how to make it work in my case.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at this example: http://gayashan-a.blogspot.com/2012/08/simple-dynamically-updating-line-chart.html

Comment: I have seen that example but it is not working I tried few things but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$('#chart_big').unbind();plot5.destroy();` and then plot with new data. Replot(); may cause memory leaks.

Refer this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14145676/jqplot-memory-leak)

Comment: I have solved my problem, there was some problem with the plot points that my graph was taking as input for replot(). Their was no problem with code. Thanks for you reply and your suggestion regarding destroy() and replot().